# SDL Tridion integration with a Java application

Tags: java, external-integrations, api

Is it possible to get content from SDL Tridion (using webservices etc.) and consume this in a Java application?

I've been reading some SDL Tridion documentation online and have seen some examples. 
What I am not able to get is the API (jar) file for Java?

Can anyone please help with the link to the core services jar file? And an example perhaps?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You really have to think of SDL Tridion in two parts (well two main parts - there's a lot more to it than that :))

1. The 'CMS' side - this could be content that is published or unpublished that lives inside the CMS - this is where you would use the 'Core Service' (a .Net web service) to put / pull content in the CMS, or perform other CMS related tasks.
2. The 'Web App', This is where your website/application is published to. - Here you've configured SDL Tridion publish specific content in a specific format.  IF the content is published dynamically (either to flat file, or database) you can use the CD (content delivery) API, which comes in 2 main flavors:  OData webservice or Java API.

So if you need to do this via point 2 - there is already all the java you need.

If you need to do this via 1) I'd check out Mihai's Google code project for using the core service with Java: https://code.google.com/p/yet-another-tridion-blog/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is what I am planning to do. I already have Tridion up and running. and I also have a java web app. Both are independent of each other at the moment. I want to modify the Java webapp so that I can get some static stuff from Tridion and use it in the java web app (client). Now I need to download Tridion Java API jar which I can use in the webapp. Where can I find this jar file?

Comment: Hi Adi, you receive the api with your installation of SDL - typically downloaded from SDL via a private link.  The install comes with java docs - you can also go onto http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html to view a lot of this information online.

Comment: Consider using the Tridion Content Delivery WebService (OData) and odata4j: http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly advise against connecting to the Content Manager (to retrieve content) from your client web application.

**As John says, there are two distinct parts and it is better to work with these than against them!**

Quite often Tridion is installed within the company network and publishes content out to a separate 'demilitarised zone' (DMZ).  If you move to this type of architecture (or if your Production environment already uses this) then you may not be able to connect to the Content Manager because of firewall rules, etc.